# How can I delete a Windows Filtering Platform rule or restore WFP to default settings?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, firewall, wfp

I am using Mullvad VPN client on Windows 10 1909 which under normal circumstances sets up Windows Filtering Platform rules that block all connections outside the VPN tunnel when the application is open and deletes the rules when the application is closed, however unfortunately last night my computer unexpectedly shut down while in the middle of using the VPN client, and when I restarted at first I had no internet access at all. I reset Windows Firewall to default settings and I now have internet access, but only over IPv4. IPv6 connections are not working and I thought the culprit was Windows Filtering Platform. I ran the command "netsh wfp show" and I see that there are multiple WFP rules still there that are blocking my IPv6 connections. The specific rule I want to get rid of is "Mullvad VPN - Mullvad VPN Firewall Integration - Block all outbound Connections (IPv6)". I have been searching for the last few hours on how I can either delete these specific rules or reset Windows Filtering Platform to default so that I can access the internet over IPv6 again, and I would really appreciate if someone who knows more about WFP than I can help.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the VPN and then immediately disconnecting?

Comment: I have tried that, as well as toggling IPv6 off and back on again and also rebooting the PC